# Test value of all members in hash variable in Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I need to run a task only if one or more files from a pre-defined list of files are missing. I tried the following (and some variants):

```
touch a

cat test.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    filelist:
      - a
      - b

  tasks:
  - stat:
      path: "{{ item }}"
    with_items: "{{ filelist }}"
    register: all_files

  - debug:
      var: all_files

  - debug:
      msg: "Some file(s) missing"
    when: "false in all_files['results'][*]['stat']['exists']"

ansible-playbook test.yml 
...
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "all_files": {
...
                "item": "a", 
                "stat": {
...
                    "exists": true, 
...
                "item": "b", 
                "stat": {
                    "exists": false
...
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "The conditional check 'false in all_files['results'][*]['stat']['exists']' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: unexpected '*'. String: {% if false in all_files['results'][*]['stat']['exists'] %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}\n\nThe error appears to have been in 'test.yml': line 16, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - debug:\n    ^ here\n"}
...
```

What is the correct syntax to use in the 'when:' clause? Or is this the wrong way altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    file_vars:
      - {name: file1}
      - {name: file2}
  tasks:
    - name: Checking existing file name
      stat:
        path: ./{{ item.name }}
      with_items: "{{ file_vars }}"
      register: check_file_name

    - debug:
        msg: 'file name {{item.item.name}} not exists'
      with_items: "{{ check_file_name.results }}"
      when: item.stat.exists == False

    - name: Create file
      file:
        path: "./{{item.item.name}}"
        state: touch
      with_items: "{{ check_file_name.results }}"
      when: item.stat.exists == False
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the trouble!